# Use custom NuGet feed in Visual Studio Online

Tags: git, nuget, build-automation, azure-devops

I've got a Visual Studio project that depends on some NuGet packages that are available from our company's feed. That feed is accessible from the web. The project is stored in Visual Studio Online in Git repository. But those NuGet packages aren't! I'd like to use VSO's automated builds and continuous integration features. How can I "tell" VSO that those NuGet packages shouldn't be downloaded from nuget.org and should be taken from www.example.com? Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a nuget.config in your solution like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="myCompany" value="http://XX.XX.XXX.XX:81/$pathToMyFeed$" />
    </packageSources>
    <activePackageSource>
        <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
    </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Note the `packageSources` section. By adding your private feed in here you make it available to the solution when resolving packages. When building, both sources should be used to resolve packages.

**NB** the nuget.config file should be located in the .nuget folder in the root of the solution

Comment: Seems, that it doesn't work. I've created a text file, named it "nuget.config" and added your content there. Also I've modified an http address for our private nuget feed. Still I'm getting an error from VSO's build system: "The type or namespace name 'XXX' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Sorry about that. When I get to work tomorrow ill try to recreate your exact scenario. Ill host a nuget gallery on a machine and host that on Azure. Then ill setup a VSO project and try to resolve a package from the azure machine. Would that be an accurate recreation of your situation?

Comment: So, I've figured out what was the problem: my nuget.config was NOT in .nuget folder and was in the root of my project. When I moved it to .nuget folder everything worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Hey, glad that worked out for you. Ill update my answer with that info in case another has the same problem. In your project did you choose to Enable Package Restore? I suspect it will work for you at the solution root too

Comment: If you are using Nuget 2.7+ then package restore is working in other way than prior to 2.7. So I've allowed Nuget to download missing packages during build by setting a check in NuGet Package Manager Options.

Comment: Are you 2.7 or higher?

Comment: Yes, sure! I'm always trying to use the latest version available.